# How does linear approximation give an approximation over an entire interval?

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

In my textbook, there is a statement as follows:
[image]

I don't understand how "linear approximation gives an approximation **over an entire interval**". I guess that it may have something to do with the fact that we factor in the interval of $x$, $\Delta x$, in the equation of linear approximation. However, I am not crystal clear on what that sentence is referring to.

Comment: I suppose that *an* needs to be replaced by *the*

Comment: you may be thinking of "an entire interval" as being large. The smaller the interval, the better the approximation.
$$g(x) = 0.25x+1$$ 
agrees with $\sqrt x$ to 8 decimal places on the entire interval $(3.9992, 4.0008)$